# How to post JSON to api in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I want to post json data to an api, but the api not receive the data from the app, although I tested the api from php script and it work fine. Any Solutions?

This api request structure

```
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "username": "some data",
  "password": "some data",
  "mobile": "some data",
  "hash": "some data"
}'
```

This is flutter function

```
static Future<String> createNewUser(String url,{String body}) async{
    Map<String,String> headers = {
      "Content-type" : "application/json",
    };
    return await http.post(url,body: body,headers: headers).then((http.Response response){
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
      print(response.body);
        if( json == null){
          throw new Exception("Error while create new account");
        }
        return response.body;
    });
  }
```

This is object encoded

```
 CreateUser createUser  = new CreateUser(
              username: "somedata",
              password:"somedata",
              mobile: "somedata",
              hash: Validation.generateHash("somedata"),
            );

            var body = jsonEncode(createUser.toMap());
            CreateUser.createNewUser(Config.URL_CREATE_NEW_USER,body: body).then((res){
              print(res);

            });
```

This is php test script

```
 $data = array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'mobile' => $mobile,
        'hash' => $hash);
    $json_data = json_encode($data);    

    $request_url = 'url here';      

    $ch = curl_init($request_url);                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);                                                              
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_data))                                                                       
    );     
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($output);
```

this is my backend php code

[this is my backend php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfmj6.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - Send Json over HTTP Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53388426/flutter-send-json-over-http-post)

Comment: can you show how you're handling the data at your back-end ?

Comment: Have you using `json.encode()` in you flutter application?

Comment: @VijayaRagavan , yes I tried by json.encode() it's the same result.

Comment: @OMiShah i don't have the backend code

Comment: If it is not reaching your sever, then you would have got an error like `SocketException`

Comment: @VijayaRagavan there is no socket exception , it is reach well,

Comment: Have you added internet permission in the androidmanifest file?